# Not able to see the images after reading html files in web browser in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have an html file which containn images.These images are kept at location same as html file.
I read the html file with the StreamReader  and navigate using navigatetoString() method.But when navigated images inside the html file are not displayed.
Below is the code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"abc.html"));
    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    browser.NavigateToString(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the images? Are they Internet URLs? Are they embedded in resources?

If you need to embed an entire page into an app, then one way to do it is to put the entire page into IsolatedStorage - including css, scripts and images

See this example - http://technodave.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/moving-files-from-xap-to-isolated-storage-for-local-html-content-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Thanks for the reply..All the images and the html file are all togther placed in a folder. No Url's are defined for them

Comment: In that case you need to follow the example on that url - copy everything to isolated storage

Comment: Is there any other way to read the images file instead of using Isolatedstorage ?

Comment: @IndianBird the next version of the browser will support data uris but until then there is no other way of doing it.

Comment: @Stuart: I did what was mentioned in the link..it worked perfect.But this code now becomes specific to the hard coded names of resources i.e If file name is abc.jpg and try.jpg then if after some time these files names changes to abc1.jpg and try1.jpg then the code needs to be changed again.Is it poosible to write it it for generic use?

Comment: I'm sure there are several ways - e.g. you could put all the files into a Resource file then use Reflection to list them.

Comment: ask this as a separate question and someone might help.